# Apps Script PUT API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, put

My goal is to update an API using Apps Script but I cannot work out how to do it. For simplicity sake here is my code:

```
let APIkey = "...";
let url = "..."

newData = {"stock_status": "instock"}

//Update API
```

The problem is I do not know how to get any further. I have read the relevant docs to this API but to no avail and I couldn't find anything about put requests in the Apps Script docs.

Comment: Does [`fetch(url, params)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) support `PUT`? (It supports `GET` and `POST`).

Comment: @andrewjames [the HTTP method for the request: get, delete, patch, post, or put. The default is get.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters)

Comment: Please first read and try with the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).*

#### Example:

I don't know how your API accepts authentication, but assuming it accepts the key as a URL parameter then you can do something like:

```js
let APIkey = "..."
let url = "..."

const newData = {
  "stock_status": "instock"
}

var options = {
  'method' : 'PUT',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(newData)
}

UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${url}?key=${APIkey}`, options);
```

You can read the full documentation on `fetch` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)